# Label not updating on button click using MVVM-Light Set

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm attempting to better understand bindings and commands in MVVM by playing around with a personal application to organize my trading cards. I am using MVVM-light library. I have run into an issue while testing where I cannot get a label to update its content after calling a RelayCommand to update the ViewModel's object. The label appears to be properly bound to the ViewModel on first load as it displays the test data, however when I fill in the textbox and click the button to update the ViewModel object, the label does not update. I confirmed that the RelayCommand is being fired because of the logging I put in place.

I have tried to change the ViewModel around and moved from using `RaisePropertyChanged("Name")` in my setter for the object and property to `Set(ref name, value)`.

### Model (Card.cs)

```cs
    public class Card {
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Atk { get; set; }
        public string Def { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public string Linkval { get; set; }
        public List<string> LinkMarkers { get; set; }
        public List<CardSet> CardSets { get; set; }
        public List<CardImage> CardImages { get; set; }
        public CardPrices CardPrices { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() {
            return $"ID: {Id}\nName: {Name}\nType: {Type}\nDescription: {Desc}\nATK: {Atk}\nDEF: {Def}\nLevel/Rank: {Level}\nRace: {Race}\nAttribute: {Attribute}";
        }
        public string ToSQLValueString() {
            //TODO: Need to figure out how to get the replacement of the ' character to work for all fields even if they're null.
            return $"({Id},'{Name.Replace("'", @"''")}','{Type.Replace("'", @"''")}','{Desc.Replace("'", @"''")}','{Atk}','{Def}','{Level}','{Race}','{Attribute}','{Linkval}','{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LinkMarkers)}','{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CardSets).Replace("'", @"''")}','{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CardImages).Replace("'", @"''")}','{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CardPrices).Replace("'", @"''")}')";
        }
    }
```

### ViewModel (CardviewModel.cs)

```cs
class CardViewModel : ViewModelBase {

        public RelayCommand<string> SaveCardCommand { get; private set; }
        private Card card;
        private string name;

        public Card CurrentCard { get { return card; } set { Set(ref card, value); } }
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { Set(ref name, value); } }
        public CardViewModel() {
            card = new Card { Id = 1, Name = "Jeff" };
            SaveCardCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(SaveCard);
        }

        private void SaveCard(string name) {
            CurrentCard.Name = name;
            Globals.Functions.WriteLog(CurrentCard.ToString());
        }
    }
```

### View (TestMVVM.xaml)

```xml
<Window x:Class="YGOBox.TestMVVM"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YGOBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestMVVM" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CardViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Example" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Example" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Card Name:  " />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentCard.Name, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="ButtonUpdateArtist" Content="Update Card Name" Command="{Binding SaveCardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,32,-12,-33" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### View Code-Behind (TestMVVM.xaml.cs)

```cs
public partial class TestMVVM : Window {
        public TestMVVM() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you creating another instance of CardViewModel in the TestMVVM constructor in the code behind?

Comment: The class Card needs to be set as ViewModelBase so it will do notifications when name is changed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am not. I've edited the post to reflect the code-behind for the View.

Comment: Oh, derp. `CurrentCard.Name` raises no notifications. Try `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentCard));` in `SaveCard()`. You'll have to do the same for any property of that object that you update while it's shown in the UI. I don't know if `RaisePropertyChanged()` is the right method name in MVVM-Light, but there'll be something like it in the view model base class.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That worked! Thank you! I'm guessing that the `Set()` method isn't implementing `RaisePropertyChanged()`. I assumed that it should be handing that call on the accessor `CurrentCard`, but I'm new to MVVM-light (and MVVM in general) so I could for sure be wrong. I'll submit your response as the answer if you put it as the answer. :)

Comment: Of course Set() raises PropertyChanged(). The problem is that the Card.Name setter never calls Set(). Card isn’t a viewmodel. You call the getter for CurrentCard, and it returns a value. You then do something to a property of that value, but at that point you aren’t interacting with anything about CurrentCard any more, and you haven’t touched CurrentCard’s setter in any case.

Comment: @KevinCook Your answer appears to be more correct when dealing with MVVM-light. When I added the implementation of ViewModelBase to the Card class and then added a `Set()` for the accessor on the Name for the Card model, it updated the label. It's a bit confusing because I wouldn't expect the Model to implement ViewModelBase, but if that's how we dos it, then that's how we dos it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett So would the better implementation be to raise `PropertyChanged()` via `Set()` in the Model, or just call `RaisePropertyChanged()` in the Command whenever I know a property has changed? Or does it matter?

Comment: Kevin's right (I somehow missed his comment before). I'd call Set() in the model. That would mean turning your Card model into a viewmodel and not having a model, properly speaking, at all. For a small project, that's very often the right thing to do. I would do that, rename Card to CardViewModel, and rename the existing CardViewModel to CardEditorViewModel, just for clarity.

Comment: In a big project, you'd have POCO classes for models, and then write a viewmodel for each one that either wraps, or duplicates it. The model is the least critical element of MVVM. The important stuff is proper viewmodel design, and a proper relationship between viewmodels and views.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you for your help. I better understand now how the VM notifies the UI. Much appreciated.